When I updated gorm version to v1.25.12, run dbresolver plugin (v1.5.2) failed
My code as follows
gormDb, err = gorm.Open(mysql.Open(fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:%d)/%s?charset=utf8mb4&parseTime=True&loc=Local", viper.GetString("mysql.username"), viper.GetString("mysql.password"), viper.GetString("mysql.host.write"), viper.GetInt("mysql.port"), viper.GetString("mysql.database"))), &gorm.Config{
        SkipDefaultTransaction: true,
        PrepareStmt:            true,
    })
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    gormSourceDb, err := gormDb.DB()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    gormSourceDb.SetMaxIdleConns(viper.GetInt("mysql.max_idle_conns"))
    gormSourceDb.SetMaxOpenConns(viper.GetInt("mysql.max_open_conns"))
    return gormDb.Use(dbresolver.Register(dbresolver.Config{
        Replicas: []gorm.Dialector{mysql.Open(fmt.Sprintf("%s:%s@tcp(%s:%d)/%s?charset=utf8mb4&parseTime=True&loc=Local", viper.GetString("mysql.username"), viper.GetString("mysql.password"), viper.GetString("mysql.host.read"), viper.GetInt("mysql.port"), viper.GetString("mysql.database")))},
    }))

When I run server, get error:
Build Error: go build -o d:\project\ecosservice\cmd\__debug_bin2894905842.exe -gcflags all=-N -l .\run_server.go
# gorm.io/plugin/dbresolver
C:\Users\83667\go\pkg\mod\gorm.io\plugin\dbresolver@v1.5.2\dbresolver.go:147:5: unknown field PreparedSQL in struct literal of type gorm.PreparedStmtDB (exit status 1)

When I downgrade gorm version to 1.25.11, it runs normally. But I hope gorm official fix it ASAP.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Update dbresolve to version 1.5.3.
